# how to find xpath, class name of elements python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, classname

My code is:

```
driver.get("http://www.thegoodguys.com.au/buyonline/SearchDisplay?pageSize=16&beginIndex=0&searchSource=Q&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&pageView=image&searchTerm=laptops")
link=();
linkPrice=();
price=();
productName=[];
Site='Harvey Norman'
link=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("photo")

linkPrice=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-title")

price=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='purchase']/span/span")
```

I am not sure whether the supplied xpath and class_name are correct. Could some one verify them and please let me know how to find them

Comment: It's nothing to say without your HTML

Comment: He gives an url in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox you can simply use the [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to check the html for classes and element ids. Following the [link](http://www.thegoodguys.com.au/buyonline/SearchDisplay?pageSize=16&beginIndex=0&searchSource=Q&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&pageView=image&searchTerm=laptops) in your question I can find a class called photo but for linkPrice and price you should use other classes.

Try:

```
price=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")
linkPrice=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("addtocart")
```

Which gives me:

```
price[0].text
u'$496'
linkPrice[0].text
u'ADD TO CART'
```

Comment: why can't I fetch product name it displace none`print productName[i]`

Comment: Result with the above changes: `$496 none`

Comment: I got wrong some where near elem, may be get_attribute("alt") fetching nothing  `for i in range(0, 16):
 elem=link[i].get_attribute("alt")
 productName.append(elem)
 print price[i].text
 print productName[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You can verify Xpath using developer tools console in chrome e.g $x("//foo") or $(".foo")
Firebug for Firefox will also let you verify

Also browsers will suggest Xpath for you but these are often verbose and unstable so would recommend hand crafting